# Save multiple records

Tags: .net, vb.net

In my Form1 I have 3 TextBox.I want when I click button1 the 3 TextBoxes will be registered at one time with ID AutoNumber..Row1 (TextBox1) .. Row2 (TextBox2) .. Row3 (TextBox3).

My code is:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   Try
            con.Open()
            Dim sqsq As String = "INSERT INTO MOUVEMENT(Row1,Row2,Row3)values('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" + TextBox2.Text & "','" + TextBox3.Text & "')"
            Dim command As New SqlCommand(sqsq, con)
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("SAVE SUCCES", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxRtlReading, "SAVE")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            MsgBox("SAVE ERROR", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxRtlReading, "ERROR")
        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection -attack. ***Always*** use paremeterized queries! Also what is your question? You didn't ask for anything or explain a problem.

Comment: Hello Esko.My question is how to correct this code to save multiple times TextBox in multiple rows

Comment: You are refererring columns as rows in your example which is really confusing, if you want to write 3 rows in the table, you need to call insert 3 times. Simple as that.

Comment: Edit your question. Post your table structure, the input in each textbox and the expected result in your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your values in an array. Then, using parameters, loop through the array executing the command with each value

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim arr As String() = {TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text}
            Dim con As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
            Try
                Dim sqsq As String = "INSERT MOUVEMENT (Colume Name) Values (@Text);"
                Dim command As New SqlCommand(sqsq, con)
                command.Parameters.Add("@Text", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                con.Open()
                For Each s As String In arr
                    command.Parameters("@Text").Value = s
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Next
                con.Close()
                MsgBox("SAVE SUCCES", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxRtlReading, "SAVE")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
                MsgBox("SAVE ERROR", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxRtlReading, "ERROR")
            Finally
                con.Close()
            End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you ery much for help.i have an error in this line : Dim arr As String = {TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text} .....Value of type 1 dimensional array of string cannot be converted to string.Thank you

Comment: OOps `Dim arr as string() = {TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text,TextBox3.Text} ` That should do it.

Comment: Thank you Mary.thank you gentelman.very nice of you.Now it works very very well.perfectly resolved.cordially.ABE